How can I write ladder program to control Load with Single pushbutton switch in PLC mitsubishi FX5U?
I want to control lamp with single pushbutton in PLC with NO NC and OUT instructions and the condition is Press switch twice to turn on Load and press once to turn off load. The ladder diagram below show what I've tried but it doesn't work.

is it possible if I don't want to use Counter or PLF PLS instructions instruction.
Thank you.

but it doesn't work <-- what attempts have you made to debug things and, what did your design actually do <-- can't make a diagnosis without symptoms.
